# How to increase download speed of the file from web-sites?

Tags: c#, .net, web, download

I have a C# console app, which downloads the files from web-sites. Here are my methods:

```
public bool DownloadFile(string fileUri, string filePath)
{
    using (var response = _GetResponce(fileUri)) {
        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) {
            return false;
        } 
        using (var responseStrm = response.GetResponseStream()) {
            using (var fileStrm = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)) {
            var buffer = new byte[CommonConstants.StreamBufferSize];
            int bytesRead = responseStrm.Read(buffer, 0, CommonConstants.StreamBufferSize);      
            while(bytesRead > 0) {
                fileStrm.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                bytesRead = responseStrm.Read(buffer, 0, CommonConstants.StreamBufferSize);
            }
        }
    }
}

private HttpWebResponse _GetResponce(string requestedUri, string method = "GET")
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestedUri);
    request.Method = method;
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13";
    request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage] = "ru-ru,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3";
    request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip,deflate";
    request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptCharset] = "windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    return (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
```

I tried to increase the buffer size, to no avail. If I add threads, can it increase download speed?

Comment: Are you sure the bottleneck is in this code and not e.g. in the network somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I was run this code on the several machines.

Comment: What is the size of `CommonConstants.StreamBufferSize` out of curiosity.. have you thought about increasing the buffer size also isn't there a `ReadAllBytes` method you could also try testing / experimenting with.?

Comment: @Alexander Have you run this code on several machines that are on different networks?  If not, they may all be simply experiencing the same bottlenecks that Rup mentioned.

Comment: The size of CommonConstants.StreamBufferSize is 8Kb, i was trying to use buffer size in the range 512b - 64Kb. I can't use ReadAllBytes, because some files has the big size (hundreds of megabytes).

Comment: Mike, it was different machines, the problem not in network.

Comment: @Alexander That wasn't the question.  Were the **different machines** on **different networks**?

Comment: If you try it on different machines *on the same network*, they're all going to be slow (because they're hooked up *to the same network*). -- Also, you should really consider just using `WebClient`, if you're just doing simple downloading, it's a one-liner: `string data = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://<download_address>");`. No need to mess around with buffers and streams and such.

Comment: I have run this code on **different machines** on **different networks**. Everywhere the same result.

Comment: Have you tried downloading files from different servers? If the download is slow from every client network, it's possible that the bottleneck is on the server's network. Try downloading the same file using a web-browser to see if that's any faster.

Comment: Yes, I've tried. The browser always downloads files faster than my app.

Comment: Can you post the `_GetResponce` method? And which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: I've added method to main question. And I use .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the server, you might gain some speed downloading the file with several segments.

For that you can use [`request.AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fy67z6d.aspx) and have different threads to download the same file. Note that when you write the data to a local file you must start in the correct offset.

This is something that most download managers do.

Note that some servers will not allow that.

Comment: Bruno, I've tried your solution and it helped for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried buffering more data before writing it to the file? In general you want to be polling the socket as quickly as possible -- it's been my experience that even if many bytes are available for reading, only a relatively small chunk of them may be returned, meaning the socket throughput ends up tied to the overhead of the rest of the loop, which could be significant.

Try this code and see if you get a measurable improvement:

```
using (var fileStrm = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
using (var responseStrm = response.GetResponseStream()) {
    const int BufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024 + CommonConstants.StreamBufferSize;
    var buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    int offset, bytesRead;
    do {    // Until we've read everything
        offset = 0;
        do {        // Until the buffer is very nearly full or there's nothing left to read
            bytesRead = responseStrm.Read(buffer, offset, BufferSize - offset);
            offset += bytesRead;
        } while (bytesRead != 0 && offset + CommonConstants.StreamBufferSize < BufferSize);

        // Empty the buffer
        if (offset != 0) {
            fileStrm.Write(buffer, 0, offset);
        }
    } while (bytesRead != 0);
}
```

Also, if you're accepting gzip and zlib streams, you'll need to turn on decompression(!):

```
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, increasing the buffer size doesn't help

Comment: @Alexander: Ah well, it was worth a try (I've seen it work in the past). Did you try the code above?

Comment: Cameron thank you for the help: I've tried your code and got download speed increase on 5-10% depending on the file size. It's not a bad, but is not enough for me.

Comment: @Alexander: Oh awesome! Might be worth playing around with the buffer size (even bigger, perhaps?), or writing to the file in a background thread.