# Parallel file download corruption

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, networking, parallel-processing

I have this code below that is able to download multiple parts of a file in parallel and writes them using a memory mapped file. The problem is occurring in the `DownloadFile()` function. The file is starting downloads properly, but it is getting corrupted along the way. For example, if I try to download a image, sections of it will be corrupted. I'm not sure if this is from some kind of race conduction in the code or if it has something to do with the content range calculations of the parts. Any help on how or were the issue is occurring would be appreciated, thanks!

Minimal, Reproducible Example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Console;

namespace ZenTester
{
internal class FileChunk
{
    public long Start { get; set; }
    public long End { get; set; }
    public FileChunk(){}
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public FileChunk(long startByte, long endByte)
    {
        Start = startByte;
        End = endByte;
    }
}

internal class RetryHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private int _maxRetries = 3;

    public RetryHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler) : base(innerHandler) { }

    public RetryHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler, int maxRetries) : base(innerHandler)
    {
        _maxRetries = maxRetries;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < _maxRetries; i++)
        {
            response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return response;
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
}

public static class ZenTester
{
    private static async Task DownloadFile(string url, int parts, string outFile = null!)
    {
        var responseLength = (await WebRequest.Create(url).GetResponseAsync()).ContentLength;
        var partSize = (long)Math.Floor(responseLength / (parts + 0.0));
        var pieces = new List<FileChunk>();
        var uri = new Uri(url);
        
        WriteLine(responseLength.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " TOTAL SIZE");
        WriteLine(partSize.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + " PART SIZE" + "\n");
        
        string filename = outFile ?? Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);

        var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, null, responseLength);

        var httpPool = new HttpClient(new RetryHandler(new HttpClientHandler(), 10)) {MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 1000000000};
        
        //Loop to add all the events to the queue
        for (long i = 0; i < responseLength; i += partSize)
        {
            pieces.Add(i + partSize < responseLength
                ? new FileChunk(i, i + partSize)
                : new FileChunk(i, responseLength));
        }

        await Parallel.ForEachAsync(pieces, parallelOptions, async (piece, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            var client = httpPool.Get();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage { RequestUri = new Uri(url) };
            request.Headers.Range = new RangeHeaderValue(piece.Start, piece.End);
                
            var message = client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;

            if (message.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                await using var streamToRead = await message.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                var streams = mmf.CreateViewStream(piece.Start, piece.End-piece.Start - 1);
                var T = streamToRead.CopyToAsync(streams);
                T.Wait();
                if (T.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
                {
                    streams.Flush();
                    streams.Close();
                }
            }
        });
        
    }
    
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var url = "https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2159447.jpg";

        var s = DownloadFile(url, 8);
        
        s.Wait();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yeah I just tried it and it's a lot cleaner than the Parallel For I was using. Thanks! Now I'm getting a System.AggregateException saying I can't expand the length of the stream. I'm assuming this is happening in the CopyToAsync() but I don't see why this would be outside the range since I'm calculating it beforehand

Comment: Yeah, I thought it would be useful to the example or have something to do with the corruption but I removed it and replaced it with a normal HTTP client.

Comment: As a side note, the `HttpClient` class is intended to be instantiated [once](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#create-and-initialize-httpclient), and reused throughout the life of an application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the corruption was happening becauase some of the ranges would be bigger than Start-End. I fixed the issue but adding a read-write modifier to both the Memory mapped file and the view stream. Then I changed the size of the view stream to the length of the content returned by the sendAsync request:

```
var streams = mmf.CreateViewStream(piece.Start, message.Content.Headers.ContentLength!.Value,
                        MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite);
```

Comment: Do you see any performance improvements, compared to downloading the file with a single asynchronous operation? (not parallel)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes I have. It's not very noticeable for smaller files but larger ones, (1+ GB) it's very noticeable compared to a single operation.

Comment: Interesting. I would expect that all the available bandwidth would be devoted at downloading the file either way. Could you share some metrics? How much faster is downloading the same 1+GB file with 2, 3, 4 parallel operations, compared to one operation?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I downloaded the 1GB test file from speed.hetzner.de by varying the 'pieces' (processes) variable to 1,2,3,4. For 1 operation I got 7:39, for 2 operations 6:34, for 3 operations 5:44, and for 4 operations 5:36.

Comment: I'm sure there's a "sweet spot" for the number of processes. Currently, just trying to optimize the code and make sure it's not blocking anywhere.

Comment: GregJ very interesting, thanks. I wonder what's the explanation for this. It looks to me more likely to be a result of a policy/resource balancing algorithm on the local machine (OS or network card), than a result of the remote server behavior.

Comment: Related: [How to increase download speed of the file from web-sites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901849/how-to-increase-download-speed-of-the-file-from-web-sites) Surprisingly most questions relevant with download speed on StackOverflow ask about how to decrease the download speed, rather than how to increase it.